# In Mobile highlighting all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[This is the link of my web site](http://demotesting.in/goodscents/scent-box.html)
IN MOBILE, When I click on one of the scent image(You can see the scent image in website), its highlighting all the image division. I have used dynamic binding on click of the image. Is there any chance that this can be reason for highlighting all the images instead of only the clicked one.

```
$(".ui-widget").on("click", "li", function(){}
```

This is the JS to detect click on the image. Is this can be reason for this?

Comment: Please open it in Mobile and then check what I am trying to say.

Comment: works fine for me, tested on Safari within iOS 7.1 simulator.